# Cannot find symbol error for Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java

I'm getting an error in the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise1
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        // declare ints for the int conversion of response, oddSum and evenSum
        final int intval = 0;
        int numb, sum=0;
        int evensum = 0, oddsum = 0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a non-negative number: (or any negative number to quit) ");
            numb = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());

            // read response into a int
            sum += numb;

            if (numb>=0&&numb/2 == 0) 
            {
                evensum += numb;
            }
            else
            {
                oddsum += numb;
            }
            System.out.print("number please");
            numb = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());

            // if the int is zero or greater do the following
            //  if it's odd print it and add it to the oddSum
            //  BUT if it's even then print it and add it to the evenSum
        } while (numb >=intval);
        System.out.println("sum of even numbers is"+ evensum);
        System.out.println("sum of odd numbers is"+ oddsum);

        // print the sum of all the odds and the evens

    } // END main
} //EOF
```

I'm getting the "cannot find symbol" error here:

```
numb = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());
```

Why is this?

Comment: Please print the actual error message, not just an excerpt.

Comment: How about reading some documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @chrylis: That is the actual error I'm getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) does not have a `readLine()` method.

Did you mean to use [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)?

Comment: If you use an IDE, it will catch these things for you and usually offer helpful suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into using an IDE.